# VBA hide cells based on value

Tags: excel, vba

I've written the following where I want the row `6:10` to be hidden if the value in cell e3 is not DWW, if it is DWW then I went the cells to reappear.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing Then
        If LCase$(Range("E3").Value) = "DWW" Then
            'if "DWW" is entered in E3, rows are Visible
            Rows("6:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            'if E3=blank or anything other than "DWW", hide rows
            Rows("6:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

My formula doesn't get the cells to reappear could anyone please help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If statement to hide/show rows in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465793/if-statement-to-hide-show-rows-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LCase` will change the value to lower case.

Either use `Ucase`:

```
If UCase$(Range("E3").Value) = "DWW" Then
```

Or match to the lower case:

```
If LCase$(Range("E3").Value) = "dww" Then
```

Comment: ah, one letter was my downfall! what if it was to have a word such which has Upper and lower cases, such as a name, e.g. Scott would i need a different letter or would i need to change the case sensitivity of my value?

Comment: no just always test either the upper or lower, then it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can been given a far more efficient answer already but you could use regex

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing Then
        Rows("6:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .Pattern = "DWW"
            If .test(Target) And Len(Target) = 3 Then Rows("6:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```